# How to set session entities when using dialogflow-fulfillment

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I recently switched to [dialogflow-fulfillment](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs) for handling fulfillment webhooks. In the API you can set `sessionEntityTypes` in the response to set Session Entity Types. Does anyone have any idea on how to do this with the library or if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but code something like this might work

```
  const entity = {/* Put your entity definition here */};
  agent.client.addJson_({sessionEntityTypes: [entity]});
```

Keep in mind that the "dialogflow-fulfillment" package has been deprecated, apparently in favor of writing the JSON manually.